# TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

So I'm trying to learn React and I got stuck trying to do a weather app.

Those are my component and my app.js files.

```css
import React from 'react'

const WeatherCard = (props) => {

    return (
     <div className="card d-flex align-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap">
        <div className= 'd-flex flex-column'>
            <img className = 'd-flex' alt='Icona' src={props.icon}></img>
            <p className ='d-flex'> {props.location} </p>
        </div>        
        <div className= 'd-flex justify-content-between'>
            <span className = "">{props.condition}</span><span className = ''>{props.temperature}°C</span>
        </div> 
     </div>
    )
}


export default WeatherCard;
```

```html
import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard';


const App = () => {
  const APP_KEY = "My_key(yes, I put my key here)";
  const [weatherDatas, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('Iglesias');

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  },[query]);

  const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${APP_KEY}&q=${query}`);
    const data = await response.json()
    setWeather(data);
  }

  const updateSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
  }

  return(
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="SearchForm d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type='text' value = {search} onChange = {updateSearch} />
        <button type='submit'>Search</button>
      </form>
      <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
        <WeatherCard 
          icon = {weatherDatas.current.condition.icon}
          location = {weatherDatas.location.name}
          condition = {weatherDatas.current.condition.text}
          temperature = {weatherDatas.current.temp_c}
        />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that when I start the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined" error pops up.

But if I remove this part of the code while it's running:

```html
          icon = {weatherDatas.current.condition.icon}
          location = {weatherDatas.location.name}
          condition = {weatherDatas.current.condition.text}
          temperature = {weatherDatas.current.temp_c}
```

refresh and past it in again it runs smoothly, I'm so confused, It looks like it tries to get the props before getting the data from the API? can someone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: you should check if text is not null or undefined,  condition = {weatherDatas.current.condition.text}

Comment: You are trying to access deeply nested properties of `weatherDatas` before they are set. The initial value of `weatherDatas` is an empty object `{}` and at initial render, none of those values as well as those deeper properties have a value, hence the error. You either need to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to only render `WeatherCard` once that data has returned/resolved from the API or update `weatherDatas` initial state value to have default values to avoid the error from happening. The render of the component does not wait for the API call.

Comment: you need to initialise state properly , set default values or use conditional rendering when you have data then only show child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classic error, as you are running an async function, for some moments when your components mount, the props received is just "{}" and that's why you receive an error. I changed your snippet, and I think now it is going to work.

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard';


const App = () => {
  const APP_KEY = "My_key(yes, I put my key here)";
  const [weatherDatas, setWeather] = useState(null); //CHANGE HERE
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); 
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('Iglesias');

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  },[query]);

  const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${APP_KEY}&q=${query}`);
    const data = await response.json()
    setWeather(data);
  }

  const updateSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
  }

  return(
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="SearchForm d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type='text' value = {search} onChange = {updateSearch} />
        <button type='submit'>Search</button>
      </form>
      <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
        {weatherDatas && ( //CHANGE HERE
          <WeatherCard 
          icon = {weatherDatas.current.condition.icon}
          location = {weatherDatas.location.name}
          condition = {weatherDatas.current.condition.text}
          temperature = {weatherDatas.current.temp_c}
        />)}
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Now your code just gonna try to render the component, when it's loaded

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful

Comment: @Pepe, do you really want that section to be removed at the first launch or if the data returns invalid information? This prevents that WeatherCard from being displayed, but it'll pop up later, potentially disrupting your layout, and if `getWeather` is run later and gets a blank or null value returned, that WeatherCard disappears again. If you are running that method regularly and your data is inconsistent, the card could flash in and out, making it unreliable or annoying. Checking for nulls in other places can allow for card visibility, even if the data is invalid.

Comment: Also a good approach is to use some <LoadingComponent/>, and you use it when you don't have wheterDatas ready to be accessed

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem caused by threading. Your variable isn't assigned a value, so it's null, and you can't pull something out of the variable so it throws the "Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined" error.

I can understand why you think the `weatherDatas` variable should be populated, due to the "await" keyword, but you have that embedded in an "async" method. In this case, "async" trumps "await".

```
const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${APP_KEY}&q=${query}`);
    const data = await response.json()
    setWeather(data);
  }
```

You will need to do null checking when using the `weatherDatas` variable. You should look into [optional chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining), which means that you'll call your object with question marks before the `.` so that it verifies data exists before trying to use the data.

There's a couple ways to do it, and they can work well or badly depending on what exactly you expect. Here's some examples, but they aren't necessarily what you want:

```
icon = {weatherDatas?.current?.condition?.icon}
location = {weatherDatas?.location.name}
condition = {weatherDatas.current.condition?.text}
```

The example for your `icon` variable is likely want you want. It prevents `icon` from being assigned anything beyond `null` unless that whole object path has data, so it won't throw the null reference error for attempting to access `weatherDatas`, `current`, or `condition`. However, `icon` can still be null if `weatherDatas.current.condition.icon` is null. This is likely the situation you want, since it checks all objects for null before accessing properties of the object. This might not be necessary for every object usage, but it's good for a single use or the use you have. Doing a regular null check would normally be better, though.

For the `location` variable, it won't throw the null reference error for trying to access `weatherDatas`, but it could for accessing `weatherDatas.location` if it's null.

In the `condition` variable example, you can still get the null reference error on `weatherDatas` and `current`, but not `condition`. Since your `weatherDatas` is null, it'll still fail in your current setup, so this isn't what you want right now.